# ol.Coordinate with direction

Tags: openlayers-3

I am trying to create a marker on a map, I have some code where if I do:

```
var iconFeature = new ol.Feature({
          geometry: new
            ol.geom.Point(ol.proj.transform([74.7951025, 40.1947151666667], 'EPSG:4326',   'EPSG:3857')),
          name: train
});
vectorSource.addFeature(iconFeature);
```

It plots the point on the map, great! The problem is its not on the correct part of the world so I need to define the directions. I tried:

```
var iconFeature = new ol.Feature({
          geometry: new
            ol.geom.Point(ol.proj.transform(["74.7951025W", "40.1947151666667N"], 'EPSG:4326',   'EPSG:3857')),
          name: train
});
vectorSource.addFeature(iconFeature);
```

I looked in the documentation for [ol.Coordinate](http://openlayers.org/en/v3.7.0/apidoc/ol.html#Coordinate) and saw nothing about direction and also saw that the coordinate should be of type `{Array.<number>}`. How do I add direction to my coordinates so the marker is in the correct spot?

Comment: You considered the coordinate order according to http://openlayers.org/en/v3.7.0/doc/faq.html#why-is-the-order-of-a-coordinate-lon-lat-and-not-lat-lon- ?

Comment: Yeah just realized that...thanks! @MichaelJS

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From what I could find, OpenLayers v3.7 does not support direction, so instead of trying to add a direction to your coordinates, you can change the latitude to negative if the direction is South and change the longitude to negative if the direction is West. This way you well get the points in the correct location.

```
var lat = parseFloat(coords[i].latitude);
if(coords[i].latitudeDir == "S")
{
    lat = lat * -1;
}
var lon = parseFloat(coords[i].longitude);
if(coords[i].longitudeDir == "W")
{
    lon = lon * -1;
}
```